# whereHas with Eager Loading in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have a question regarding whereHas in Laravel

```
   public function index($category = null) {
        $videos = Video::with(['content', 'content.categories' => function($query) use ($category) {
            return $query->where('name', $category);
        }])->paginate(10);

        return view('frontend.videos')->with('videos', $videos);
    }
```

Take that method, i have a Video model, the **Video Model** has a 1-to-1 relationship with the **Content Model** which in turn has a many-to-many relationship with the **Categories Model**
I need to get all videos where the which have a content with a category where the name matches whatever has been searched, is this possible? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, the final solution looks something like this, the eager loading will get me the Categories Model in the Subquery and i can simply use that and check against it.

```
$videos = Video::whereHas('content.categories', function($categories) use ($category) {
    $categories->where('name', $category);
})->paginate(10);
```